# How to unit test timer() observable with jasmine marbels

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I'm trying in angular application to unit test ngrx effect that introduces some polling logic using timer and maps to some actions depending on the value from some selector.

My code is something like that:

```
@Injectable()
export class YourEffects {
  timerEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(fromActions.startTimerAction),
      switchMap(() =>
        timer(0, 1000).pipe(
          withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectCondition)),
          map(() => {
            if (condition) {
              return fromActions.timerTickAction1()
            }

            return fromActions.timerTickAction2()
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}
}
```

I managed to unit test this with `fakeAsync` [using this approach](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-timer-rxjs-testing?file=src%2Fapp%2Fm1%2Fc1.component.spec.ts), but have troubles doing that with Jasmine Marbels

Tried to shift time with jasmine like that

```
it('should emit timerTickAction every second', () => {
  // Arrange
  store.overrideSelector(selectCondition, someFalsyValue);
  const startAction = fromActions.startTimerAction();
  const tickAction = fromActions.timerTickAction2();

  // Act
  actions = hot('-a', { a: startAction });

  // Use jasmine.clock().install() to control the passage of time
  jasmine.clock().install();

  // Simulate the passage of time and test the effect
  jasmine.clock().tick(1000); // 1 second
  const expected = cold('-b', { b: tickAction });

  // Assert
  expect(effects.timerEffect$).toBeObservable(expected);

  // Clean up the clock
  jasmine.clock().uninstall();
});
```

Would really appreciate if someone can suggest the way to test this using marbles. Thanks!

Comment: https://rxjs.dev/guide/testing/marble-testing#marble-syntax Check out the time progression part

Answer (score 0):

From some of my own testing I found that with `jasmine-marbles` I can test observables with `timer` or `interval` only if they are run inside `TestScheduler.run()` callback. I was not able to find a thorough explanation of why it is that way.

Another point is that when writing marble tests you must have your observables complete at some point. As is sometimes the case with `timer` or `interval` if no completion mechanism is passed in source code or in the test setup, the observable is never complete and the test won't be working because of it. This is mentioned in this issue on `rxjs` repo: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3957

Also take a look at this piece of documentation on marble testing: https://rxjs.dev/guide/testing/marble-testing#time-progression-syntax.
This will explain why in our marbles we use `999ms` instead of `1s`.

With all of this in mind this is how I would test your effect code:

```
it('should emit twice, on start and after 1s', () => {
  // given
  store.overrideSelector(selectCondition, someFalsyValue);
  const startAction = fromActions.startTimerAction();
  const tickAction = fromActions.timerTickAction2();

  const scheduler = getTestScheduler();
  scheduler.run(() => {
    // when
    actions$ = hot('a', {
      a: startAction
    });

    // then
    const expected = cold('a 999ms (a |)', {
      a: tickAction
    });
    expect(effects.timerEffect$.pipe(take(2))).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
});
```

`getTestScheduler()` is import from `jasmine-marble`, same for `hot` and `cold`.

If the `take(3)` is used instead of `take(2)` your output marble should be looking like this `a 999ms a 999ms (a |)`.

Hope this helps.